# How to specify the report pdf name at run time?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report named "Debt Report ". It runs for every month and a pdf is generated at the first of the month by subscription option.
If I am running the report for the month then the report name of the pdf should be "Debt Report for April" and like wise if I run it for may then the name of the pdf should be "Debt Report for May".

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are [scheduling the report to a file share](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159264%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), you can set the name of the file share to be `Debt Report for @timestamp` - this will name the file in the format `Debt Report for` *YYYY_MM_DD_HRMINSS* .

If you only want the month name (not the entire timestamp) to appear in the filename, you will need to use a [Data Driven Subscription](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156012%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: i figured out that the Data Driven subscription can be used for this purpose but i am getting an error named "Cannot read the next data row for the dataset ." for the subscriptions.. can you help me out with this?

Answer (score 0):

Another option, although a bit more technical, is to use the rs.exe utility to generate the report. This involves:

- creating a script file that generates the report (this is where you can set the filename to your preference)
- creating a batch file that calls rs.exe with the script file as a parameter
- running the batch file on a schedule e.g. with Windows scheduler or SQL Server Agent

There is an example here of how to do this (to create Excel files but the principle is the same) http://skamie.wordpress.com/2010/08/11/using-rs-exe-to-render-ssrs-reports/

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this problem is "Data Driven Subscription"
 http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms169972(v=sql.105).aspx
http://www.kodyaz.com/reporting-services/create-data-driven-subscription-in-sql-server.aspx

the following link helped me alot but the query given in the link creates trouble- cast the datatype of the getdate and it will solve the problem

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sqlreportingservices/thread/0f075d9b-52f5-4a92-8570-43bbdaf2b2b1

Answer (score 0):

I have had to do the same thing ( well almost )

I had to generate a weekly report to file and save it as REPORT-Week01.pdf, then REPORT-Week02.pdf etc.

The mechanism I used was to change the parameter column in the Schedule table via a scheduled job. This computed the required file name and simply replaced it. Then when the scheduled job runs, it writes to the file name setup when the schedule was created ( except that was changed at 1 minute past midnight to what I wanted it to be )

I have since implemeted another set of reports that write to a folder, whihc changes each month the the next months folder name ( currently writing all reports to  a folder called 202103 ) tonight the job will run and the output folder will change to 202104 and the scheduled jobs will never need changing